# Powershell remove row from CSV that contains string

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to remove rows, here is my example

```
"Name","Local_IP","Remote_IP"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 pc-00017 SymantecServer mserver-4: mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 pc-00017 SymantecServer mserver-4: mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 pc-00017 last message repeated 3 times","","
"Sep  1 03:55:57 pc-00017 SymantecServer mserver-4: mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 pc-00017 last message repeated 2 times","","
"Sep  1 03:55:57 pc-00017 SymantecServer mserver-4: mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
```

I need to remove the row that has the "last message repeated" removed.

I have tried with no luck.

```
$test = import-csv myfile.csv | where {$_.Name -notcontains "repeated"}
$test | export-csv myfile.csv -notype
```

Any help plese?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work I think :

```
Get-Content C:\Path\myfile.csv | Where{$_ -notmatch "repeated"} | Out-File C:\Path\myNewFile.csv
```

Comment: Almost... If you use `Get-Content` you then do not have a `Name` property, so it becomes `Where{$_ -notmatch "repeated"}`

Comment: The problem I am having now is the `Get-Content` strips away the CSV format and makes the data unusable.

Answer (score -1):

`-contains` is designed to work on arrays, not so good for strings. As per Sylvain's answer `Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "repeated"}` should do what you want.

For more information, check out [the Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847759.aspx). If nothing else it tell you that match uses regular expressions so as not to trip over this down the line.